# What would be the equivalent or closest match of Activated event of Window in Page in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

There is `Activated` event in a Window in WPF. What is the the closest match for Activated event for a page. I want to use an event that triggers every time a page is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the IsVisibleChanged event.

In your window, either your base class definition that you use throughout your app, or just the one you are interested in.  Add a call at the opening of it something like

```
public class MyBaseclassWindow : Window
{
   public MyBaseclassWindow()
   {
      IsVisibleChanged += MyBaseclassWindow_IsVisibleChanged;
   }

   private void MyBaseclassWindow_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      // e.NewValue will be TRUE when the visibility is coming back on
      if ( !e.NewValue )
         return;

      // do whatever you want every time window becomes visible.
   }
}
```

If this is something you want done throughout your system, then you can just use THIS window as your base window by always using it as forms are created.

Comment: This event fires before Load event. This is not good. Try `MessageBox.Show("test")` it will generate an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=netframework-4.8) event which occurs when the element (`Page`) is laid out, rendered, and ready for interaction.

The `Frame` class, which I guess is used to host your pages, also has a `ContentRendered` event that you can handle.

Comment: yes, a Frame class hosts my page in a Window but if I use ContentRendered event then the code of page with its variables code will go in Window, I guess? because the frame is defined in the Window and not page. What are your thought? Doesn't seem the right way for me.

Comment: The Loaded event fired only once, I want an event to fire every time the page is displayed, like in Activated event.

Comment: It should fire each time the page is loaded into the visual tree.